# Why am I getting a 'version solving failed' error when installing flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0 package and how can I address it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I tried to add  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0 package.
When I run flutter pub get, I get the following error:"last line of pub output: "flutter_slidable >=3.0.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=3.7.0, version solving failed.""

I changed sdk: '>=2.19.0-146.2.beta <3.7.0'. Still getting the same error

Comment: try `sdk: '>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'`